# How do I name a many-many table for EF6 and do I need to add special mapping for this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am using EF 6 and trying to map a many to many relationship. So far I have:

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public ObjectiveDetail()
    {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubTopic
{
    public SubTopic()
    {
        this.ObjectiveDetails = new List<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Our DBA is going to write the code for the many to many table. Should this be as follows 
with a table name of `ObjectiveDetailSubTopic` or something completely different ?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectiveDetailSubTopic] (
    [ObjectiveDetailId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SubTopicId]        INT NOT NULL
);
```

Can someone tell me if this is the correct way to create the table. Also do I have to 
add some code to map the ObjectiveDetail and SubTopic classes to the new join class so
EF will know what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Our DBA is going to write the code for the many to many table. Should
>   this be as follows with a table name of ObjectiveDetailSubTopic or
>   something completely different ?

As long as you follow the SQL Database table naming conventions, the table name can be anything. I usually name the join table like yours, by connecting the two table names.

To create the  join table using sql, see below:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectiveDetailSubTopic](
        ObjectiveDetailSubTopicId int identity primary key,
        ObjectiveDetailId INT NOT NULL,
        SubTopicId  INT NOT NULL,
        foreign key(ObjectiveDetailId) references ObjectiveDetail(ObjectiveDetailId ),
        foreign key(SubTopicId) references SubTopic(SubTopicId )
    );
```

But you don't need to create the join table by your own, `Entity Framework` will create it for you. You just need to mapping the relationship with the Fluent API in your DbContext class like below:

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectiveDetail>().
            HasMany(c => c.SubTopics).
            WithMany(p => p.ObjectiveDetails).
            Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.MapLeftKey("ObjectiveDetailId ");
                        m.MapRightKey("SubTopicId ");
                        m.ToTable("ObjectiveDetailSubTopic");
                    });
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me if the primary key is really needed? I see in the ASP.NET Identity where there is a similar many to many then that table has no primary key.

Comment: If you let Entity Framework  to generate the join table, you just need to map the relationships.
Of course you don't need to think about primary keys. If you create the join table on your own in SQL,
you need to create primary key property. Because you showed the SQL command about create the join table,
I thought you want to create the join table by yourself, that's why I wrote the primary key property.